# C#: Temporarily capture OnClick event in parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a Windows Forms application and I want to be able to show a 'post-it note' type thing when the user does a specific action.

For example: The user does something which automatically hides a control.

My application should:
 o Pop up a post it note which explains what happened. 
 o Hide the post it note again when the user clicks anywhere on the form.

I have implemented the post it note as a simple panel with a label in it, which shows and hides when specific things happen.

However, I can't seem to capture the OnClick event of the parent UserControl.  The parent control is a nested control, containing a split container, one side of which contains the panel and a tab control, each of which contains a user control with various things in it.

Apart from handling the click event of every single child control, can anyone think of an event that I can capture on the parent control that I can use to hide the post it note when the user clicks anywhere in the parent control?

Thanks,
Rik

Comment: Would the mousedown of the form not be sufficient?

Comment: In this simple scenario, why not use a Windows.Forms.Timer? After 5 seconds (or a configurable value) the popup will be closed in the Tick event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the Capture property was designed to do.  Set it to *true* when you pop up the note.  Any mouse events will now be directed to your control, even if the mouse moves outside of the window.  This is also the way that, for example, the combobox dropdown list works.  Keep in mind that it is only good for one click.

If the popup contains any controls itself then mouse capture isn't the solution.  Make it an owned form instead and simply call Close() in an event handler for the Deactivate event.

Answer (score -1):

There is bubling of events in windows form, while you click on child event, the event is raised for child, and then for parent. Unless you specify "handleEvnet" property to true. So just leave it false, untill event reaches parent.

Comment: The [Windows Forms `Control.Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event supplies only an instance of the [`EventArgs` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which does not have a property like `HandleEvent` or `Handled`.